# SQL syntax error: SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently started with SQL and I am trying to get all "ua_keys" generated by a random sample of 10,000 customers within a month.
When running the following SQL query:

```sql
    WITH
    selected_users AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            user_id
        FROM
            oneapp_data.oa_events
        WHERE
            logtime BETWEEN '2020-10-01T21:59:57.940Z' AND '2020-11-01T22:59:58.027Z'
        ORDER BY rand()
        LIMIT 10000
    )
    SELECT
        user_id,
        ua_key
    FROM
        oa_events
    WHERE
        ua_key IN ( selected_users)
```

retrieving the following error:

> Error running query: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:4: For SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Any ideas of how can I solve this?  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It looks to me like your `rand()` field in the ORDER BY section should be part of the result set in order to be usable in the `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a sub-query SELECT Statement into the IN clause.
Try the one bellow:

```
WITH
selected_users AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        user_id,
        ua_key, 
        rand() random_value
    FROM
        oneapp_data.oa_events
    WHERE
        logtime BETWEEN '2020-10-01T21:59:57.940Z' AND '2020-11-01T22:59:58.027Z'

),
sampling_example AS(

SELECT 
  user_id,
  ua_key, 
  random_value
FROM 
  selected_users
ORDER BY 
  random_value
LIMIT 10000
)

SELECT
    user_id,
    ua_key
FROM
    oa_events
WHERE
    ua_key IN ( 
      
      SELECT ua_key
      FROM sampling_example

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
WITH selected_users AS (
      SELECT TOP (10000) distinct user_id
      FROM oneapp_data.oa_events
      WHERE logtime BETWEEN '2020-10-01T21:59:57.940Z' AND '2020-11-01T22:59:58.027Z'
      ORDER BY NEWID()
    )
SELECT user_id, ua_key
FROM oa_events
WHERE ua_key IN (SELECT user_id FROM selected_users);
```

If fixing the `IN` clause doesn't work, you can do:

```
WITH selected_users AS (
      SELECT TOP (10000) user_id
      FROM oneapp_data.oa_events
      WHERE logtime BETWEEN '2020-10-01T21:59:57.940Z' AND '2020-11-01T22:59:58.027Z'
      GROUP BY user_id
      ORDER BY NEWID()
    )
```

Comment: @cherencia . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?